# Creating/accessing/modifying nested Python lists of unspecified dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array

An API call of mine returns a dict of multi-dimensional data. Each item in the dict is a piece of data and which corresponds to a key of the form

```
"index1:index2: ... :indexN"
```

This is a string of integers separated by colons and it indicates that the data item occurs at position index1 in the first dimension, index2 in the second dimension, etc, up to indexN in the Nth dimension.

I would like to take this dictionary of data and use it to populate a multi-dimensional list for further analysis. Ideally this would mean iterating over the dict and interpreting the key as a list of indices, a la

```
index_list = [int(i) for i in key.split(':')]
```

Unfortunately I am automating several related (but different) API calls to populate several different instances of a Data wrapper class, and the datasets are not of fixed dimension. I therefore can't hard code an assignment like

```
data[index1][index2]...[indexN] = dict[key]
```

Is there a Pythonic way to create, access, and modify a multi-list using a second list as index values? Something which "feels like"

```
data[*args] = dict[key]
```

with

```
args = index_list
```

maybe (even though this is obviously nonsense pseudocode)?

Comment: You're missusing the name `dict` and creating a lot of confusion. Please change that to another name. What you have as a string annotated with colons is just a string. There's no `dict` here.

Comment: No, it is a dict. The string annotated with colons is the key which corresponds to a data entry in the dict. The dict looks like many hundreds of entries of {"index1:index2:...:indexN" : data_val}

Comment: @MichaelCromer, No, you haven't *defined* any dictionary in your post. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @jpp This is true, but unrelated to the initial comment. I would have provided a MWE, but how do you write a working example exhibiting a programming concept you are asking about the existence of? I can't write a "working example" of something I don't know about; that's the purpose of the question. How would *you* write a MWE?

Comment: Start with `An API call of mine returns a dict of multi-dimensional data.` Why not print an extract of this? Then define it *explicitly* in your question. Like `my_dict = {1: 'adsfasdf', 2: 'fsgsd'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way of doing it, but this works:

```
def lookup(data, indices):
    if len(indices) == 1:
        return data[indices[0]]
    return lookup(data[indices[0]], indices[1:])
```

Assignment would work the same way:

```
def assign(data, indices, value):
    if len(indices) == 1:
        data[indices[0]] = value
    lookup(data[indices[0]], indices[1:])
```

**Edit** Perhaps a cleaner approach, using a different object than the default `dict()`:

```
class MultiDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        item = super().__getitem__(key[0])
        if len(key) > 1:
            item = item[key[1:]]
        return item

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(key) > 1:
            if key[0] not in self:
                super().__setitem__(key[0], MultiDict())
            super().__getitem__(key[0])[key[1:]] = value
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key[0], value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if len(key) > 1:
            del super().__getitem__(key[0])[key[1:]]
        else:
            super().__delitem__(key[0])

    # Converts nested dicts recursively
    def dimensionalize(self):
        for key in self:
            item = super().__getitem__(key)
            if type(item) == dict:
                super().__setitem__(key, MultiDict(item))
                super().__getitem__(key).dimensionalize()
        return self
```

Just convert your nested `dict`s to `MultiDict`s, then index them directly with a list or tuple. For example:

```
b = MultiDict({1:{3:4}}).dimensionalize()

indices = (1,3)
print(b[indices])
# Prints 4

b[2,5] = 6
print(b[2,5])
# Prints 6
```

Comment: This was my initial thought too...if there are no fancier answers forthcoming I will accept this as correct...

Comment: @MichaelCromer updated with a cleaner usage alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `reduce` is pythonic, but you can do it succinctly. Some sample data, square dimensions:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: data = numpy.arange(32).reshape((2,2,2,2,2))
```

We're just going to use integers for because you know how to split a string.

```
In [3]: nums = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1] # 1+4+8 = 13

In [4]: def getindex(x, i):
   ...:     return x[i]
   ...:
   ...:
```

So simply:

```
In [5]: from functools import reduce

In [6]: def indexer(data, ix):
   ...:     return reduce(getindex, ix, data)
   ...:
   ...:

In [7]: indexer(data, nums)
Out[7]: 13
```

You can use a tidy little class:

```
In [17]: def _to_nums(keys):
    ...:     return map(int, key.split(':'))
    ...:
    ...: class DataAccessor:
    ...:     def __init__(self, data):
    ...:         self.data = data
    ...:     def indexer(self, ix):
    ...:         return reduce(getindex, ix, self.data)
    ...:     def assign(self, key, value):
    ...:         *ix, last_index = _to_nums(key)
    ...:         lastdim = self.indexer(ix)
    ...:         lastdim[last_index] = value
    ...:     def select(self, key):
    ...:         return self.indexer(_to_nums(key))
    ...:

In [18]: accsr = DataAccessor(data)

In [19]: key = '0:1:0:1:1' # 1 + 2 + 8 = 11
In [20]: accsr.select(key)
Out[20]: 11
```

And assignment:

```
In [21]: accsr.assign('1:1:1:1:1', 42)

In [22]: accsr.select('1:1:1:1:1')
Out[22]: 42

In [23]: data[0,1,0,1]
Out[23]: array([10, 42])
```